# Count polylines crossing each raster cell

Tags: arcpy, feature-count

I'm looking for the best way to count polylines crossing each raster cell and assign that count value to the raster cell using arcpy.

On input I have a shapefile with hundred thousands of polylines and a raster with all cells  0 values.

The result should be a raster which cells value should be a number of crossing polylines from the shapefile.

Which ArcPy tools should I use to perform this analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could easily be built in model builder. I would:

1. Convert your raster to points
2. Convert your points back into a raster but using FID as the value column, this will create unique raster cells
3. convert this new raster to a polygon dataset
4. Run the intersect tool, this will give your count of lines per individual pixel.
5. Join count to polygon and rasterize if required.

Comment: Great. Regarding point 4: Intersect tool I run like this: arcpy.analysis.Intersect([lines_file, out_grid], out_intersect, "", "", "LINE") It gives me single lines cut to pixel borders. I still need to count lines in the pixels before performing join. Of course now it is easier to count, because I can count using pixels Id. Or is there another way to get count of the lines per pixel?

Comment: You are correct, you use the ID and run that through the [summary statistics tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm), that should be step "4.5".   :)